# Existence of weak primitive

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, weak-derivatives

Let $f\in L^p(\Omega),$ then does there exist a function $u$ on $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
the weak derivative of $u$ is f?

In other words, does differential equation $u'=f$ admits a distributional solutions $u$ which is also a function on $\Omega$.

If such a solution $u$ exists, then does $u \in L^p(\Omega)$ always?

Comment: What are the requirements on your set $\Omega$? Is it one dimensional?

Comment: To begin with, is the result true in one dimension? If yes, does it hold in higher dimensions as well?

Comment: In higher dimensions, you must be careful when writing $u' = f$, since there are many generalizations of the one-dimensional case. I.e., $u$ and $f$ are scalar fields and you only take a partial derivative $\partial_x u = f$; or $u$ is a vector field and you take the divergence $\operatorname{div}u = f$ or $f$ is a vector fields and you take the gradient $\nabla u = f$....

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $f$ is in $L^p$ guarantees that $f$ is locally integrable. Indeed, if $K\subset\Omega$ is compact, then by Hölder
$$
\int_K|f|=\int_\Omega |f|\,1_K\leq\|f\|_p\,|K|^{1/q}<\infty. 
$$

In dimension $1$, using that  $f$ is locally integrable, we can define
$$
u(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f.
$$
Then for a test function $\phi$ we have $\def\abajo{\\[0.2cm]}$
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega u\phi'&=\int_\Omega\phi'(x)\,\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\,dx\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R}f(t)\int_t^\infty\phi'(x)\,dx\,dt\\
&=-\int_{\mathbb R}f(t)\phi(t)\,dt=-\int_\Omega f\phi.
\end{align}

Fubini is justified because $f$ is locally integrable and $\phi'$ has compact support, hence the integral occurs in a compact set where $f\,\phi'$ is integrable.

It's not obvious to me that this idea can be pushed to higher dimensions, where the natural generalization of the FTC is Stokes' theorem, and I wouldn't know (haven't thought much about this) how to deal with the region when using Fubini.